# Capture specific request with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I would like to capture the full request (raw_request -- what went over the wire) for a given action without using a proxy.

I am aware of the debug_output method on the Class, and that might be part of the solution.  But unclear on how to set it on a per request basis.

Consider the following ...

```
@response = HTTParty.post(@job.callback_url, body: @job.to_json)
notification = Notification.new
notification.response_body = @response.body
notification.response_code = @response.code
notification.request_body = ????
```

Thanks!

Jonathan

Answer (score 19):

`@response.request` will contain the request object.

Comment: how do I get the raw_request?

Comment: @Jonathan I would not recommend this except to debug your code, but to answer your question and get at the raw request, you can use ruby's `instance_variable_get` method: `@response.request.instance_variable_get(:@raw_request)`

Answer (score 18):

```
      HTTParty.post(url, :body => body, :debug_output => $stdout)
```

Comment: I've been looking for this everywhere!

Answer (score 9):

Add the following under your `include HTTParty` line:

```
debug_output $stdout
```

This sets an output stream for debugging and the output stream is passed on to Net::HTTP#set_debug_output.

Comment: "I am aware of the debug_output method on the Class, and that might be part of the solution. But unclear on how to set it on a per request basis."

Comment: I've added this, but how do I view the output? I'm not seeing it in my logs.